# Bootstrap 3 side panel 100% height of parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So here's my situation
[image]

I need the sidebar to go down all the way but I can't get it to do that. I've tried searchning here as well. It is probably very simple and I can't see it because I've been working on this for a while.

My code:

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="site-box">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="header">
                        <!-- HEADER -->
                        <!-- Logo -->
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="header-logo">
                                <span class="logo">Zikle</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Search -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                            <div class="header-search">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <form class="header-search-form" role="search">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoeken..." aria-label="Zoeken">
                                        <span class="input-group-btn" id="basic-addon1"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button></span>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Control Panel -->
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-3">
                            <div class="header-controlpanel"><div class="pull-right">
                                <span><kbd>Dani&euml;l</kbd></span> <img src="http://www.zikle.nl/userfiles/thumbs/0/2/5/4/02546700.png" width=40 height=40 style="border-radius: 50%; cursor: pointer">
                            </div></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Left MENU -->
                    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm left-content-box">

                        <div class="side-menu">
                            <img src="http://www.zikle.nl/userfiles/thumbs/0/2/5/4/02546700.png" width=90 height=90>
                            <span class="user">
                                <span class="name"><a href="/">Dani&euml;l</a></span>
                                <span class="title">- Designer</span><br><hr style="margin: 5px;">
                                <span class="karma">+788</span> Karma<br>
                                <span class="gray">423</span> Credits<br>
                                <span class="gray">4881</span> Forum berichten<br>
                                <span class="gray">615</span> Plaatjes<br>
                                <span class="gray">96</span> Vrienden<br>
                            </span>

                            <div class="sub-menu">
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Mijn pagina's</a></li>
                                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- CONTENT -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 right-content-box">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                              <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Index</a></li>
                              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Instellingen</a></li>
                              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Mijn pagina's</a></li>
                              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Mijn berichten</a></li>
                              <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Crumbs -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                              <li><a href="#">Zikle</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>

                        <!-- SHOUTS -->
                        <div class="col-xs-2">
                            <div class="shout-panel2 pull-right">
                                <div class="shout-user">
                                    <a href="/"><img class="shout-avatar" src="http://www.zikle.nl/userfiles/thumbs/0/2/5/4/02546700.png" width="30" height="30">
                                    <span class="shout-name">Dani&euml;l</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-8">
                            <div class="panel panel-default shout-panel">
                              <div class="panel-body shout-body">
                                <span class="shout-message">Nieuw Zikle design.. omg</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                            <div class="shout-panel2">
                                <div class="shout-date">
                                    <span>17-9-2015</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- forum -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 forum-box">
                        <div class="forum-panel">
                            <span></span>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Melanie</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:08)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Jesse</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:02)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daniel</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (16-9-2015 | 22:20)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (15-9-2015 | 13:58)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Iwan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (14-9-2015 | 13:11)</span><br>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Melanie</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:08)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Jesse</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:02)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daniel</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (16-9-2015 | 22:20)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (15-9-2015 | 13:58)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Iwan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (14-9-2015 | 13:11)</span><br>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 visible-lg">
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Melanie</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:08)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Jesse</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (17-9-2015 | 17:02)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daniel</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (16-9-2015 | 22:20)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Daan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (15-9-2015 | 13:58)</span><br>
                                <br>
                                <a href="/">lorum ipsum dolor</a><br>
                                <span style="font-size:11px; color: #222">door: <a href="/">Iwan</a> | <a href="/">Laatste bericht</a> (14-9-2015 | 13:11)</span><br>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <!-- footer -->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <footer>
                                &copy; Zikle - 2015 Alle rechten voorbehouden.
                            </footer>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    color: #222;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

/*
 * Remove text-shadow in selection highlight:
 * https://twitter.com/miketaylr/status/12228805301
 *
 * These selection rule sets have to be separate.
 * Customize the background color to match your design.
 */

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

/*
 * A better looking default horizontal rule
 */

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Remove the gap between audio, canvas, iframes,
 * images, videos and the bottom of their containers:
 * https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/440
 */

audio,
canvas,
iframe,
img,
svg,
video {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*
 * Remove default fieldset styles.
 */

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * Allow only vertical resizing of textareas.
 */

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Browser Upgrade Prompt
   ========================================================================== */

.browserupgrade {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Zikle
   ========================================================================== */

body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: none;
        margin-top: 2em;
}

body {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Roboto,arial,sans-serif;
        color: #111;
        background-image: url("../img/bg-pattern.gif");
}

body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
        margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

.site-box {
        background: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-width: 0px;
        min-height: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 3em;
        margin-top: 3em;
}

.header {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
        min-height: 55px;
}

.header-logo .logo {
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        font-size: 36px;
        padding-left: 35px;
}

.header-search {
        padding-top: 10px;
}

.header-controlpanel {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 2em;
}

.form-control {
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.42857;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #f7f8fa;
        background-image: none;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in 0s;
}

.form-control:focus {
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        outline: 0px none;
        box-shadow: none;
        width: 325px;
}

.header-search .btn-default {
        color: #222;
        background-color: #f7f8fa;
        border-color: #f7f8fa;
        transition: 0.25s ease-in 0s;
}

.header-search .btn-default:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

footer {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 35px;
        color: #ccc;
}

.left-content-box {
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
}

.right-content-box {

        float: left;
        position: relative;
}

.breadcrumb {
        border-radius: 0px;
        background: #f7f8fa;
}

.nav-pills > li > a {
        border-radius: 0px;
}
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a {
        transition: 0.35s ease;
}
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover {
        background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus, .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover {
        background-color: #337AB7;
}

.side-menu {
        border-right: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
        background: #f7f8fa;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 15px;
}

.side-menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: top
}

.side-menu span.user {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 1.2;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.side-menu span.name {
        font-size: 14px;
}

.side-menu span.title {
        color: #333;
}

.side-menu span.karma {
        color: green;
}

.side-menu span.gray {
        color: #888;
}
.shout-panel {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        border-radius: 4px;
}
.shout-panel:before {
        content: ''; position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 100%; height: 0; width: 0; border: 7px solid transparent; border-right: 7px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.shout-panel2 {
        display: inline-block;
}

.shout-date {
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
}
.shout-user {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-top: 10px;
}
.shout-user img.shout-avatar {
        border-radius: 50%;
}
.shout-date span {
        color: #888;
        font-size: 10px;
}

.forum-box {
        margin-left: 20px;
}

.extra-panel {
    background: #f7f8fa;
        border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
        border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
}

.center-block {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
}
.realign-inline {
        display: inline;
        text-align: left;
}

[class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Zikle MENU
   ========================================================================== */


/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers:
 */

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}

/*
 * Hide only visually, but have it available for screen readers:
 * http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility
 */

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/*
 * Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element
 * to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard:
 * https://www.drupal.org/node/897638
 */

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

/*
 * Hide visually and from screen readers, but maintain layout
 */

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

/*
 * Clearfix: contain floats
 *
 * For modern browsers
 * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
 *    `contenteditable` attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
 *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
 *    that receive the `clearfix` class.
 * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
 *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
 */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   EXAMPLE Media Queries for Responsive Design.
   These examples override the primary ('mobile first') styles.
   Modify as content requires.
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (min-width: 35em) {
    /* Style adjustments for viewports that meet the condition */
}

@media print,
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 1.25dppx),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Style adjustments for high resolution devices */
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles.
   Inlined to avoid the additional HTTP request:
   http://www.phpied.com/delay-loading-your-print-css/
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster:
                                   http://www.sanbeiji.com/archives/953 */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links that are fragment identifiers,
     * or use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol
     */

    a[href^="#"]:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    /*
     * Printing Tables:
     * http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables
     */

    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

CSS code: http://pastebin.com/3hQ1jSsa

Comment: Well we really need to see your CSS as well, but `height: 100vh;` would probably do it.

Comment: @TylerH `height:100vh` is used to set a div to the height of the browser window. This would be a great solution if the element is going to be `position:fixed`.

Comment: @ether I'm aware of what `height:100vh` does. As I said in my first comment, we need to see OP's CSS.

Comment: no lol that takes the full viewport height and that is not what  I need. It makes the parent very large http://i.imgur.com/BDmZhd3.png

Comment: I can't post my css because the post does very weird. I can upload it somewhere http://pastebin.com/3hQ1jSsa

Comment: would you be able to provide a link to the actual sight where this is occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered a well known issue. There currently isn't an elegant solution to resolve this but you do have a few options.

There are a few CSS hacks which involve setting the display as a table or playing with margin and padding heights. These are documented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851/4907529

There is also a JavaScript way of resolving it, whereby on page load the height of the sidebar is dynamically updated to match that of the main content area:

https://jsfiddle.net/use97noq/

This basically uses the following function to run on load and on page resize to match the height of the main content body:

```
function setHeight(elementToResize, elementToMatch){
    $(elementToResize).height(elementToMatch.height());
}
```

Like I said, no elegant way to resolve it (atleast until `display:flex` is better supported), you'll just need to take your pick from the best of a bad bunch currently.

Comment: Ok, so I tried the examples you linked, none of them work. At least, they don't make the height 100% but they simply mess up my design for example everything gets stacked on top of each other. Your javascript does work, but  I don't really like to have to rely on javascript. It actually makes the box a bit bigger, but I just added overflow: hidden

Comment: @mrbanaan - No problem..the linked examples should work but depending on the classes you apply it to, it could mess up other styles on the page. For the JavaScript solution, you could experiment with changing one of the `height` functions to `innerHeight` or `outerHeight`. I know, none of these solutions are great (I hate using unnecessary JavaScript) but it's what we have to work with currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:Your Color Here;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: @mrbanaan Is the side bar going to be fixed?

Comment: ? the bar is just always on the left but it needs the height of he parent (the white box that you can hardly see) It is sort of like the youtube sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Give the row containing the sidebar a class, such as sidebar-container

Then add this css

```
.sidebar-container{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.left-content-box{
    height: 9999px;
}
```

This is a bit unorthodox, but it would be easier to help if I have access to a fiddle or a link to the site. But this has worked for me on several occasions.